# Does $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right)$ converge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'm not really sure how to start here, the basic tests don't work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$\sin(\pi/n) = \pi/n + O(1/n^2)$ for $n$ large. Now use the fact that the harmonic series diverges.

Answer (score 7):

Remember the usual limit from basic calculus

$$
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} = 1
$$

Now, can you think of a way to use this basic limit in combination with the [limit comparison test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test) to conclude something about the convergence or divergence of your series? Off course you'll have to take $a_n = \sin{\left( \dfrac{\pi}{n} \right)}$ as one of your sequences ;-)

Comment: Beat me to it :)

Answer (score 3):

Use the [limit comparison test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test), with the series $b_n =1/n$. Since:
$$\lim_{x\to0} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} =1$$
And since $b_n$ diverges, so does $a_n = \sin(\pi/n)$.

Comment: Why not use the **plain** comparison test with $b_n=\dfrac2n$, seeing as $\sin x\ge\dfrac{2x}{\pi}$ for $x\in[0,\pi]$, and so $\sin\dfrac{\pi}n\ge\dfrac2n$ for $n\ge2$?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Approximate the sine function by a straight line.  What if it were a line?  Then use the limit comparison test.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert #1 \right\vert}%
 \newcommand{\yy}{\Longleftrightarrow}$

Since $\sin\pars{x} \geq 2x/\pi$ when $0 \leq x \leq \pi/2$:
\begin{align}
\sum_{n = 1}^{N}\sin\pars{\pi \over n}
&=
\sum_{n = 2}^{N}\sin\pars{\pi \over n}
\geq
\sum_{n = 2}^{N}{2 \over \pi}\,{\pi \over n}
=
2\sum_{n = 2}^{N}{1 \over n}
=
2\sum_{n = 1}^{N}{1 \over n} -1
\end{align}

The right hand side diverges when $N \to \infty$ !!!.